# Apache2 not accepting connections

Tags: apache, ubuntu

We just had a server migration, and things really messed up.  First all the data was gone, (Thank god for backups), and now apache just isn't responding (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT).

Server is running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

The apache vhost setup is good.  It's from the previous setup which worked, and wasn't changed.  Either way here is the config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/versions/prod/Application/UIAdmin"
        ServerName adminca.decision.io
        ServerAlias adminca.decision.io

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/decisionio.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/decisionio.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/intermediate.crt

        <Directory "/var/www/versions/prod/Application/UIAdmin">
                AllowOverride all
                allow from all
                Options -Indexes
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

traceroute goes to the right place.

ping goes to the right place.

iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I'm not really a server admin, just got thrown into the position, so I have no idea where to search next!  Any help would be helpful.  I can post more configs if requested.

**Edit**

I think it has something to do with the listening ports?  Would the tcp6 have any influence on this?

```
$ netstat -nl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49630           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::50499                :::*
```

**Edit #2**
It seems like wget is getting the application, not too sure where the routing problem exists then...

*On the server*:

```
$ wget http://127.0.0.1/ -O -
--2015-10-24 22:00:05--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: Login [following]
--2015-10-24 22:00:05--  http://127.0.0.1/Login
```

wget on my local also goes to the right server, but it times out.

*On my local:*

```
$ wget https://adminca.decision.io -O -
--2015-10-24 22:17:07--  https://adminca.decision.io/
Resolving adminca.decision.io... 104.36.151.37
Connecting to adminca.decision.io|104.36.151.37|:443... failed: Operation timed out.
Retrying.
```

wget on http requests does the same thing as well.